# Flex mobile app using sqlite: selecting from db

Tags: database, sqlite, apache-flex, select

I am developing an app with FLEX using an SQLite database with a table users (firstName, lastName, password) inserting data in this table is no problem but when i want to select data i get the same error **(Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.)**

my code for selecting:

```
  selectStmt = new SQLStatement;
  selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
  selectStmt.text = "SELECT firstName FROM users";
  selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
  selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
  selectStmt.execute();
```

my code for the resultHandler:

```
    public function resultHandler(event:SQLEvent):void
    {
    var result:SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult();
    if(result == null)
    {
        lblFeedback.text = "nul";
    }
    else
    {
    var numResults:int = result.data.length;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < numResults; i++)
    {
        var row:Object = result.data[i];
        var output:String = "iD: " + row.itemId;
        output += "; fName: " + row.firstName;
        output += "; lName: " + row.lastName;
        output += "; passwd: " + row.password;
        lblFeedback.text = output;
    }
    }
            }
```

var result is not null but it seems to go wrong while doing: var numResults:int = result.data.length;

Can someone help me? Been looking for a while now and this is really frustrating!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If there are no records returned then `.data` is null, so its probably the `data.length` part that's throwing your error.